# Emulating Multiple Inheritance C#

Tags: c#

```
public class A2
{
  protected virtual void f() {Console.WriteLine("from A2");}
  protected virtual void g() {Console.WriteLine("From A2");}
  protected virtual void h1() {Console.WriteLine("from A2");}
}

public class B2
{
  protected virtual void f() {Console.WriteLine("B2");}
  protected virtual void g() {Console.WriteLine("B2");}
  protected virtual void h2() {Console.WriteLine("B2");}
}
```

giving this code above, I am trying to inherit all the functionality of the 2 classes by creating a new class as following:

```
public class C2 
{
    private A2 a2 = new A2();
    private B2 b2 = new B2();

    public void f()
    {
        a2.f();
    }

    public void h1()
    {
        a2.h1();
    }

    public void g()
    {
        b2.g();
    } 

    public void h2()
    {
        b2.h2();
    } 


    static public void Main() 
    {
        C2 n = new C2();
        n.f();
        n.g();
        n.h1();
        n.h2();

    }

}
```

However, when I'm trying to compile the program I'm getting an error that is I can't access the protected methods. 
How would I inherit all the functionality without modifying the class `A2`, and `B2`?

Comment: This isn't inheritance, this is having A2 and B2 as dependencies. Very different. As the members are marked `protected`, they cannot be accessed from outside of the class or a class which inherits from it.

Comment: You could make a wrapper class that inherits from `A2` and then provides `new` methods that pass through to the base implementation, exposing the protected methods as public ones.

Comment: C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, and you can't access `protected` fields unless you're derived from the class. You'd have to make them public or write a wrapper that exposes them.

Comment: @RufusL You should mention that we use interfaces to achieve multiple class inheritance in C#

Answer (score 0):

This is one of disadvantages of C# abstract and virtual classes - no multiple inheritance. Abstraction is essentially a dependance to parent, but why there should be one dependence?

As for the solution of your problem, you need to make them public before combining them:

```
public class A2
{
  protected virtual void f() {Console.WriteLine("from A2");}
  protected virtual void g() {Console.WriteLine("From A2");}
  protected virtual void h1() {Console.WriteLine("from A2");}
}

//make a wrapper which will publish protected methods
//ADVICE: always use interfaces, they MUCH more flexible as you will see in your own example, use abstract/static modifier with caution.
public interface IA2
{
    void f_public();
    void g_public();
    void h1_public();
}
public class PublicA2 : A2, IA2
{  
   public void f_public(){f();}
   public void g_public(){g();}
   public void h1_public(){h1();}
}
//do the same for B2
```

And then you can combine them and even mark them with coresponding interfaces:

```
public class C2 : IA2, IB2
{
    private readonly IA2 _a2;
    private readonly IB2 _b2;

    public C2(IA2 a2, IB2 b2)
    {
        _a2 = a2;
        _b2 = b2;
    }

    public void f_public()
    {
        _a2.f_public();
    }

    public void h1_public()
    {
        _a2.h1_public();
    }

    public void g_public()
    {
        _b2.g_public();
    } 

    public void h2_public()
    {
        _b2.h2_public();
    } 
}
```

Comment: "This is one of disadvantages of abstract and virtual classes - no multiple inheritance" - hmmm... not exactly sure where do you see link between these two concepts... C++ has abstract and virtual classes... yet it has multiple inheritance just fine. You probably meant to say something different...

Comment: Well, in C++ it is much better If I can say so. In C# this is banned for whatever crazy reason Microsoft has. I said this in context of C#, many other languages has classes and I didn't mean them all, because for example Python will allow multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Derive classes that expose the behavior in public methods.  Compose the composite class from the derived types.

```
public class A2_Derived : A2
{
    public void FMethod() => f();
    public void GMethod() => g();
    public void H1Method() => h1();
}

public class B2_Derived : B2
{
    public void FMethod() => f();
    public void GMethod() => g();
    public void H2Method() => h2();
}

public class C2 
{
    private A2_Derived a2 = new A2_Derived();
    private B2_Derived b2 = new B2_Derived();

    // implement the methods you need...
}
```

Comment: It's good to NOT use obscure modifier like 'new', because they behave completely stupid with casting. In production development it is doomed at review level. Use interfaces.

Comment: This example doesn't have any methods where `new` would hide an inherited member anyway. The base class methods are named `f`, `g`, and `h1` or `h2`. The derived class is using `F`, `G`, and `H1` or `H2`. Or they were before the last edit :].

Comment: Yes, the case was intended to communicate that we were not trying to preserve method signature.  Renamed the methods to communicate that more explicitly.